# No Sound in Audio React native web view

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

Hello I implement Web view in react native using
react-native-webview

Web view render successfully but there is no sound in it I also run web on browser there is sound enable also run in HTML5 iframe there is also sound but when i Implement this with react native web view there is no sound

Web view Code
 `<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://lita.org.uk/litamoodle/chat2/voicecall.php' }} javaScriptEnabled={true} domStorageEnabled={true} mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture={false} onLoad={() => console.log('WebView loaded')} onError={(error) => console.error('WebView error', error)} onMessage={(event) => console.log('event.nativeEvent.data',event.nativeEvent.data)} style={{ flex: 1 }} />`

Permission in android
I also add this permissions in android
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`

I want to show a web view in react native successfully render but there is no sound play in webView